# Page not found (404) Battery not found

Tags: python, html, django, blockchain

[the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYf3g.png)
[this is what the battery_registration_success page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxpIp.png)
I cant get my web application to generate static qr codes. I am building a django web application. My project is "Fake phone battery identification using blockchain technology". The user must enter the phone battery's details to register it in the system. Once successfully registered, the user will be given a unique battery id and a link to generate the qr code. When i click the link i get this error:

```
2023-06-28 14:08:17 [WARNING] django.request: Not Found: /fontriden/fontriden/qr_code/c549194f808cf837a9595b94b6eba295b902024bfa859f61ae72d589ce6eca59/
[28/Jun/2023 14:08:17] "GET /fontriden/fontriden/qr_code/c549194f808cf837a9595b94b6eba295b902024bfa859f61ae72d589ce6eca59/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5475
```

this is what my views.py looks like:

```
def battery_registration_success(request):
    w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi=contract_abi)
    battery_id = request.session.get('battery_id')
    numeric_battery_id = int(battery_id, 16)  # Convert hexadecimal string to integer
    qr_code_url = reverse('qr_code_image', args=(battery_id,))
    battery_details = get_battery_details(w3, contract, battery_id)
    context = {
        'battery_details': {
            'battery_id': battery_id,
            'product_name': battery_details[0],
            'certification_mark': battery_details[1],
            'serial_number': battery_details[2],
            'watt_hours': battery_details[3],
            'qr_code_url': qr_code_url,
def qr_code_image(request, battery_id):
    try:
        battery = Battery.objects.get(id=str(battery_id))
    except Battery.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Battery not found")
    qr_image = generate_qr_code(battery)
    qr_image_data = qr_image.getvalue()
    battery_details = get_battery_details(battery_id)
    qr_code_filepath = generate_qr_code(battery, battery_details)

    
    context = {
        'battery_details': {
            'battery_id': battery.battery_id,
            'product_name': battery_details[0],
            'certification_mark': battery_details[1],
            'serial_number': battery_details[2],
            'watt_hours': battery_details[3],
            'qr_code_filepath': qr_code_filepath,
        }
    }

    return render(request, 'generate_qrcode.html', context)

def generate_qr_code(battery, battery_details):
    qr_code_filename = f'battery_qr_{battery_details["battery_id"]}.png'
    qr_code_filepath = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'fontriden', 'qr_codes', f'battery_qr_{battery.id}.png')
    details = f"Product Name: {battery_details['product_name']}\nCertification Mark: {battery_details['certification_mark']}\nSerial Number: {battery_details['serial_number']}\nWatt Hours: {battery_details['watt_hours']}, {battery.watt_hours}"

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H, box_size=5, border=4)
    qr.add_data(details)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    qr_image = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    qr_image.save(qr_code_filepath)
    return qr_code_filepath
```

this is what my urls.py looks like:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
urlpatterns = [    
path('fontriden/qr_code/<str:battery_id>/', views.qr_code_image, name='qr_code_image'),
]
```

this is what my models.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Add any additional fields for the Manufacturer model

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Battery(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(to='fontriden.Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    certification_mark = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    watt_hours = models.IntegerField()
    qr_code_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    qr_code_filepath = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

Can someone please help me with this?

I have tried adding a new html code for when i click on the "Generate QR code" and this is what it looks like:

```html
<h1>Generated QR Code</h1>
<img src="{{ battery_details.qr_code_filepath }}" alt="QR Code">
<p>Battery ID: {{ battery_details.battery_id }}</p>
<p>Product Name: {{ battery_details.product_name }}</p>
<p>Certification Mark: {{ battery_details.certification_mark }}</p>
<p>Serial Number: {{ battery_details.serial_number }}</p>
<p>Watt Hours: {{ battery_details.watt_hours }}</p>
```

and yet it still doesnt work

Comment: Where is the code which inserts into `Battery` model?

Comment: class Battery(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(to='fontriden.Manufacturer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    certification_mark = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    watt_hours = models.IntegerField()
    qr_code_url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    qr_code_filepath = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects